# Sending message to a api with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

In JavaScript, create a text input and a submit button.
Send the content of the text field to the API when the submit button is clicked. Only do this if it contains at least 1 character.

I have a text field and sumbit button, but how do I make the connection with the api using a query and how can I make sure it only sends something to the api if it needs at least 1 charachter?

Comment: Using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) and an `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Without any of your code, it's really difficult to guess what you've tried. But anyway, here's my approach.

First listen for the click event on the `button`:

```js
yourButton.addEventListener('click', fetchAPI);
```

Then perform the necessary checks and query the API

```js
function fetchAPI() {
  // Check if the input has something in it
  if (yourTextField.value === '') return;
  
  // Change this to whatever your API expects
  const query = 'https://api.example.com/?text=${yourTextField.value}';
  
  // Use AJAX to query the API
  fetch(query, {
    method: 'POST', // Or GET
  })
    .then((response) => response.json()) // Only if the response is in JSON, otherwise use response.text()
    .then((data) => {
      // Handle the response
    })
  
}
```